# RoR Save data in related tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relational-database

I am using the associations, here the documentation:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

The idea is that I want to generate a statement that inside the controller account can save the data in the account table and the transfer table that are related

I have the following models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :account
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :transfers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Transfer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account, optional: true
  has_one :commission, dependent: :destroy
end

class Commission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :transfer, optional: true
end
```

and I am using the following instruction to save data:

```
@transfer = @account.transfers.create (: order_date => Time.now)
```

The problem is that when executing the program it tells me that the **transfers** method is not defined

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `transfers' for nil: NilClass):
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing

Comment: Actually what it is telling you is that the `@account` variable is `nil`.  Just one thing, is it a typo that there is a space between the `@` and `account` in you code above, or is it that way in your controller?

Comment: Can you add the controller code where this is being saved?

Comment: The error means that `@account` isn't defined or failed to lookup.  Without seeing your controller code its hard to assist more than this.  But you either didn't set `@account` anywhere (any undefined instance variable is always nil/NilClass), or it failed to lookup and your Account lookup code returned nil.